# What does this list permutations implementation in Haskell exactly do?

Tags: list, haskell, permutation, combinatorics

I am studying the code in the Data.List module and can't exactly wrap my head around this implementation of permutations:

```
permutations            :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations xs0        =  xs0 : perms xs0 []
  where
    perms []     _  = []
    perms (t:ts) is = foldr interleave (perms ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
      where interleave    xs     r = let (_,zs) = interleave' id xs r in zs
            interleave' _ []     r = (ts, r)
            interleave' f (y:ys) r = let (us,zs) = interleave' (f . (y:)) ys r
                                     in  (y:us, f (t:y:us) : zs)
```

Can somebody explain in detail how these nested functions connect/work with each other?

Comment: Would ask some specific questions that you have about it? What pieces do you understand?

Comment: Well mostly I can't follow what perms and interleave/interleave' are doing. Is there any particular algorithm that this implementation is based on?

Comment: As for the relationship between `interleave` and `interleave'`, I don't know why `interleave xs r` is not defined as `snd $ interleave' id xs r`.

Comment: But no, I haven't the foggiest notion what `interleave` or `interleave'` are *supposed* to do.

Comment: The reason this function is so complicated is that it is trying really hard to be maximally lazy. For example, you can run `map (take 3) $ permutations (1:2:3:undefined)` and get `[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[1,3,2]*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`; but not get undefined sooner. The mailing list discussion should provide some insight into its design, http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Add-subsequences-and-permutations-to-Data-List-ticket-1990-td3173688.html

Comment: @TwanvanLaarhoven, could you possibly explain what `interleave` is supposed to do? It's a bit opaque.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote that code, so I'll have to figure it out again myself as well. I do remember that the `f` parameter is a function that is mapped over the final result. I will make a more detailed writeup later today.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sorry about the late answer, it took a bit longer to write down than expected.

---

So, first of all to maximize lazyness in a list function like this there are two goals:

- Produce as many answers as possible before inspecting the next element of the input list
- The answers themselves must be lazy, and so there the same must hold.

Now consider the `permutation` function. Here maximal lazyness means:

- We should determine that there are at least `n!` permutations after inspecting just `n` elements of input
- For each of these `n!` permutations, the first `n` elements should depend only on the first `n` elements of the input.

The first condition could be formalized as

```
length (take (factorial n) $ permutations ([1..n] ++ undefined))) `seq` () == ()
```

David Benbennick formalized the second condition as

```
map (take n) (take (factorial n) $ permutations [1..]) == permutations [1..n]
```

Combined, we have

```
map (take n) (take (factorial n) $ permutations ([1..n] ++ undefined)) == permutations [1..n]
```

Let's start with some simple cases. First `permutation [1..]`. We must have

```
permutations [1..] = [1,???] : ???
```

And with two elements we must have

```
permutations [1..] = [1,2,???] : [2,1,???] : ???
```

Note that there is no choice about the order of the first two elements, we can't put `[2,1,...]` first, since we already decided that the first permutation must start with `1`. It should be clear by now that the first element of `permutations xs` must be equal to `xs` itself.

---

Now on to the implementation.

First of all, there are two different ways to make all permutations of a list:

1. Selection style: keep picking elements from the list until there are none left

   ```
   permutations []  = [[]]
   permutations xxs = [(y:ys) | (y,xs) <- picks xxs, ys <- permutations xs]
     where
       picks (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [(y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- picks xs]
   ```
2. Insertion style: insert or interleave each element in all possible places

   ```
   permutations []     = [[]]
   permutations (x:xs) = [y | p <- permutations xs, y <- interleave p]
     where
       interleave []     = [[x]]
       interleave (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (interleave ys)
   ```

Note that neither of these is maximally lazy. The first case, the first thing this function does is pick the first element from the entire list, which is not lazy at all. In the second case we need the permutations of the tail before we can make any permutation.

To start, note that `interleave` can be made more lazy. The first element of `interleave yss` list is `[x]` if `yss=[]` or `(x:y:ys)` if `yss=y:ys`. But both of these are the same as `x:yss`, so we can write

```
interleave yss = (x:yss) : interleave' yss
interleave' [] = []
interleave' (y:ys) = map (y:) (interleave ys)
```

The implementation in Data.List continues on this idea, but uses a few more tricks.

It is perhaps easiest to go through the [mailing list discussion](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Add-subsequences-and-permutations-to-Data-List-ticket-1990-td3173688.html). We start with David Benbennick's version, which is the same as the one I wrote above (without the lazy interleave). We already know that the first elment of `permutations xs` should be `xs` itself. So, let's put that in

```
permutations xxs     = xxs : permutations' xxs
permutations' []     = []
permutations' (x:xs) = tail $ concatMap interleave $ permutations xs
  where interleave = ..
```

The call to `tail` is of course not very nice. But if we inline the definitions of `permutations` and `interleave` we get

```
permutations' (x:xs)
  = tail $ concatMap interleave $ permutations xs
  = tail $ interleave xs ++ concatMap interleave (permutations' xs)
  = tail $ (x:xs) : interleave' xs ++ concatMap interleave (permutations' xs)
  = interleave' xs ++ concatMap interleave (permutations' xs)
```

Now we have

```
permutations xxs     = xxs : permutations' xxs
permutations' []     = []
permutations' (x:xs) = interleave' xs ++ concatMap interleave (permutations' xs)
  where
   interleave yss = (x:yss) : interleave' yss
   interleave' [] = []
   interleave' (y:ys) = map (y:) (interleave ys)
```

The next step is optimization. An important target would be to eliminate the (++) calls in interleave. This is not so easy, because of the last line, `map (y:) (interleave ys)`. We can't immediately use the foldr/ShowS trick of passing the tail as a parameter. The way out is to get rid of the map. If we pass a parameter `f` as the function that has to be mapped over the result at the end, we get

```
permutations' (x:xs) = interleave' id xs ++ concatMap (interleave id) (permutations' xs)
  where
   interleave f yss = f (x:yss) : interleave' f yss
   interleave' f [] = []
   interleave' f (y:ys) = interleave (f . (y:)) ys
```

Now we can pass in the tail,

```
permutations' (x:xs) = interleave' id xs $ foldr (interleave id) [] (permutations' xs)
  where
   interleave  f yss    r = f (x:yss) : interleave' f yss r
   interleave' f []     r = r
   interleave' f (y:ys) r = interleave (f . (y:)) ys r
```

This is starting to look like the one in Data.List, but it is not the same yet. In particular, it is not as lazy as it could be.
Let's try it out:

```
*Main> let n = 4
*Main> map (take n) (take (factorial n) $ permutations ([1..n] ++ undefined))
[[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1]*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Uh oh, only the first `n` elements are correct, not the first `factorial n`.
The reason is that we still try to place the first element (the `1` in the above example) in all possible locations before trying anything else.

---

Yitzchak Gale came up with a solution. Considered all ways to split the input into an initial part, a middle element, and a tail:

```
[1..n] == []    ++ 1 : [2..n]
       == [1]   ++ 2 : [3..n]
       == [1,2] ++ 3 : [4..n]
```

If you haven't seen the trick to generate these before before, you can do this with `zip (inits xs) (tails xs)`.
Now the permutations of `[1..n]` will be

- `[] ++ 1 : [2..n]` aka. `[1..n]`, or
- `2` inserted (interleaved) somewhere into a permutation of `[1]`, followed by `[3..n]`. But not `2` inserted at the end of `[1]`, since we already go that result in the previous bullet point.
- `3` interleaved into a permutation of `[1,2]` (not at the end), followed by `[4..n]`.
- etc.

You can see that this is maximally lazy, since before we even consider doing something with `3`, we have given all permutations that start with some permutation of `[1,2]`. The code that Yitzchak gave was

```
permutations xs = xs : concat (zipWith newPerms (init $ tail $ tails xs)
                                                (init $ tail $ inits xs))
  where
    newPerms (t:ts) = map (++ts) . concatMap (interleave t) . permutations3
    interleave t [y]        = [[t, y]]
    interleave t ys@(y:ys') = (t:ys) : map (y:) (interleave t ys')
```

Note the recursive call to `permutations3`, which can be a variant that doesn't have to be maximally lazy.

As you can see this is a bit less optimized than what we had before. But we can apply some of the same tricks.

The first step is to get rid of `init` and `tail`. Let's look at what `zip (init $ tail $ tails xs) (init $ tail $ inits xs)` actually is

```
*Main> let xs = [1..5] in zip (init $ tail $ tails xs) (init $ tail $ inits xs)
[([2,3,4,5],[1]),([3,4,5],[1,2]),([4,5],[1,2,3]),([5],[1,2,3,4])]
```

The `init` gets rid of the combination `([],[1..n])`, while the `tail` gets rid of the combination `([1..n],[])`. We don't want the former, because that would fail the pattern match in `newPerms`. The latter would fail `interleave`. Both are easy to fix: just add a case for `newPerms []` and for `interleave t []`.

```
permutations xs = xs : concat (zipWith newPerms (tails xs) (inits xs))
  where
    newPerms [] is = []
    newPerms (t:ts) is = map (++ts) (concatMap (interleave t) (permutations is))
    interleave t []         = []
    interleave t ys@(y:ys') = (t:ys) : map (y:) (interleave t ys')
```

Now we can try to inline `tails` and `inits`. Their definition is

```
tails xxs = xxs : case xxs of
  []     -> []
  (_:xs) -> tails xs

inits xxs = [] : case xxs of
  []     -> []
  (x:xs) -> map (x:) (inits xs)
```

The problem is that `inits` is not tail recursive. But since we are going to take a permutation of the inits anyway, we don't care about the order of the elements. So we can use an accumulating parameter,

```
inits' = inits'' []
  where
  inits'' is xxs = is : case xxs of
    []     -> []
    (x:xs) -> inits'' (x:is) xs
```

Now we make `newPerms` a function of `xxs` and this accumulating parameter, instead of `tails xxs` and `inits xxs`.

```
permutations xs = xs : concat (newPerms' xs [])
  where
    newPerms' xxs is =
      newPerms xxs is :
      case xxs of
        []     -> []
        (x:xs) -> newPerms' xs (x:is)
    newPerms [] is = []
    newPerms (t:ts) is = map (++ts) (concatMap (interleave t) (permutations3 is))
```

inlining `newPerms` into `newPerms'` then gives

```
permutations xs = xs : concat (newPerms' xs [])
  where
    newPerms' []     is = [] : []
    newPerms' (t:ts) is =
      map (++ts) (concatMap (interleave t) (permutations is)) :
      newPerms' ts (t:is)
```

inlining and unfolding `concat`, and moving the final `map (++ts)` into `interleave`,

```
permutations xs = xs : newPerms' xs []
  where
    newPerms' []     is = []
    newPerms' (t:ts) is =
        concatMap interleave (permutations is) ++
        newPerms' ts (t:is)
      where
      interleave []     = []
      interleave (y:ys) = (t:y:ys++ts) : map (y:) (interleave ys)
```

Then finally, we can reapply the `foldr` trick to get rid of the `(++)`:

```
permutations xs = xs : newPerms' xs []
  where
    newPerms' []     is = []
    newPerms' (t:ts) is =
        foldr (interleave id) (newPerms' ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
      where
      interleave f []     r = r
      interleave f (y:ys) r = f (t:y:ys++ts) : interleave (f . (y:)) ys r
```

Wait, I said get rid of the `(++)`. We got rid of one of them, but not the one in `interleave`.
For that, we can see that we are always concatenating some tail of `yys` to `ts`. So, we can unfold the calculating `(ys++ts)` along with the recursion of `interleave`, and have the function `interleave' f ys r` return the tuple `(ys++ts, interleave f ys r)`. This gives

```
permutations xs = xs : newPerms' xs []
  where
    newPerms' []     is = []
    newPerms' (t:ts) is =
        foldr interleave (newPerms' ts (t:is)) (permutations is)
      where
      interleave ys r = let (_,zs) = interleave' id ys r in zs
      interleave' f []     r = (ts,r)
      interleave' f (y:ys) r = 
        let (us,zs) = interleave' (f . (y:)) ys r
        in  (y:us, f (t:y:us) : zs)
```

And there you have it, `Data.List.permutations` in all its maximally lazy optimized glory.

---

Great write-up by Twan! I (@Yitz) will just add a few references:

- The original email thread where Twan developed this algorithm, linked above by Twan, is fascinating reading.
- Knuth classifies all possible algorithms that satisfy these criteria in Vol. 4 Fasc. 2 Sec. 7.2.1.2.
- Twan's `permutations3` is essentially the same as Knuth's "Algorithm P". As far as Knuth knows, that algorithm was first published by English church bell ringers in the 1600's.

Comment: Doesn't your `interleave` function (at least the first ones) miss the `x` in its parameter list?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by inserting vs. selecting.

Comment: @Bergi: since the `interleave` function is declared in a `where` block, the variables `x` and `xs` are in scope since they are the arguments to the outer function, `permutations`.

Comment: @dfeuer: to make the permutations of `[1,2,3]` there are two strategies:
* take the permutations of `[2,3]`, which are `[[2,3],[3,2]]` and consider all places to insert `1` into these lists.
* consider all possible start of the permutation, which are `1`, `2` or `3` (select an element from the input), and continue with a permutation of the remaining elements.

Comment: @TwanvanLaarhoven: Yeah, I've seen that (even if it looked a little unconventional), but at least in the first example there was a mistake. Please check my edit :-)

Comment: It would seem to me that the most natural way to express the general algorithm is as an `unfoldr`. The seed looks something like `(smaller,currentElement,currentTail)`, where `smaller` is a list of permutations of the first `n` elements. At each step, `currentElement` is interleaved into each element of `smaller`, and each of those permutations is prepended to `currentTail`. There are a couple `concat`s to put everything together. I'm rather curious whether there's any way to make that efficient without twisting everything into knots.

Comment: Perhaps you may care to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507769/4543207) and i would be very glad to have a comment from you. That algorithm seems to run like **1.33x** faster in average compared to the `Data.List.permutations` if i am not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

The basic algorithm is based on the idea of taking one item from the list at a time, finding every permutation of items including that new one, and then repeating.

To explain what this looks like, [1..] will mean a list from one up, where no values (no even the first) have been examined yet. It is the parameter to the function. The resulting list is something like:

```
[[1..]] ++
[[2,1,3..]] ++
[[3,2,1,4..], [2,3,1,4..]] ++ [[3,1,2,4..], [1,3,2,4..]]
[[4,3,2,1,5..], etc
```

The clustering above reflects the core idea of the algorithm... each row represents a new item taken from the input list, and added to the set of items that are being permuted. Furthermore, it is recursive... on each new row, it takes all the existing permutations, and places the item in each place it hasn't been yet (all the places other then the last one). So, on the third row, we have the two permutations [2,1] and [1,2], and then we take place 3 in both available slots,  so [[3,2,1], [2,3,1]] and [[3,1,2], [1,3,2]] respectively, and then append whatever the unobserved part is.

Hopefully, this at least clarifies the algorithm a little. However, there are some optimizations and implementation details to explain.

(Side note: There are two central performance optimizations that are used: first, if you want to repeatedly prepend some items to multiple lists, `map (x:y:z:) list` is a lot faster then matching some conditional or pattern matching, because it has not branch, just a calculated jump. Second, and this one is used a lot, it is cheap (and handy) to build lists from the back to the front, by repeatedly prepending items; this is used in a few places.

The first thing the function does is establish a two bases cases: first, every list has one permutation at least: itself. This can be returned with no evaluation whatsoever. This could be thought of as the "take 0" case.

The outer loop is the part that looks like the following:

```
perms (t:ts) is = <prepend_stuff_to> (perms ts (t:is))
```

`ts` is the "untouched" part of the list, that we are not yet permuting and haven't even examined yet, and is initially the entire input sequence.

`t` is the new item we will be sticking in between the permutations.

`is` is the list of items that we will permute, and then place `t` in between, and is initially empty.

Each time we calculate one of the above rows, we reach the end of the items we have prepended to the thunk containing (perms ts (t:is)) and will recurse.

---

The second loop in is a foldr. It for each permutation of `is` (the stuff before the current item in the original list), it `interleave`s the item into that list, and prepends it to the thunk.

```
foldr interleave <thunk> (permutations is)
```

---

The third loop is one of the most complex. We know that it prepends each possible interspersing of our target item `t` in a permutation, followed by the unobserved tail onto the result sequence. It does this with a recursive call, where it folds the permutation into a stack of functions as it recurses, and then as it returns, it executes what amounts to a two little state machines to build the results.

Lets look at an example: `interleave [<thunk>] [1,2,3]` where `t = 4` and `is = [5..]`

First, as interleave' is called recursively, it builds up `y`s and `f`s on the stack, like this:

```
y = 1, f = id
y = 2, f = (id . (1:))
y = 3, f = ((id . (1:)) . (2:))
(the functions are conceptually the same as ([]++), ([1]++), and ([1,2]++) respectively)
```

Then, as we go back up, we return and evalute a tuple containing two values, `(us, zs)`.

`us` is the list to which we prepend the `y`s after our target `t`.

`zs` is the result accumulator, where each time we get a new permutation, we prepend it to the results lists.

Thus, to finish the example, `f (t:y:us)` gets evaluated and returned as a result for each level of the stack above.

```
([1,2]++) (4:3:[5..]) === [1,2,4,3,5..]
([1]++) (4:2[3,5..])  === [1,4,2,3,5..]
([]++) (4:1[2,3,5..]) === [4,1,2,3,5..]
```

---

Hopefully that helps, or at least supplements the material [linked in the author's comment above](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Add-subsequences-and-permutations-to-Data-List-ticket-1990-td3173688.html).

(Thanks to dfeuer for bringing this up on IRC and discussing it for a few hours)